# Proof of the inequality for the tail of the maximum of sums of independent random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $ \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n $ be independent random variables with $ \mathbf{E}\xi_i = 0 $ for $ 1\le i \le n. $ I need to prove that for all $ a>0 $
$$ \mathbf{P}(\max_\limits{1\le k \le n} S_k \ge a) \le 2 \mathbf{P}(S_n \ge a-\mathbf{E}|S_n|), $$
where $ S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \xi_k. $

I tried a lot of ways to solve this problem, but none were completed.

The first approach, that I tried to implement, was using the next statement:

$\textbf{Statement:}$
Denote $S_n^* = \max_\limits{1\le k \le n} S_k $ then for all $a, b \in \mathbf{R}$
$$ \mathbf{P}(S_n^* \ge a) \le \frac{\mathbf{P}(S_n\ge a-b)}{\max_\limits{1\le k \le n} \mathbf{P}(S_n - S_k \ge -b)}. $$
I tried to use it taking $ b = \mathbf{E}|S_n|$. All I needed to prove here is that
$$ \mathbf{P}(S_n - S_k \ge -\mathbf{E}|S_n|)\ge \frac{1}{2}. $$
I have done the next:
$$ \mathbf{P}(S_n - S_k < -\mathbf{E}|S_n|) = \mathbf{P}(S_k - S_n > \mathbf{E}|S_n|)\le \mathbf{P}(|S_n - S_k| > \mathbf{E}|S_n|) $$
and here in need to show that it is less than 1/2. But I don't know how to do that.

The second approach was to draw an analogy with the proof of Levi's inequality for the median-centered maximum sums. I introduced the next events:
$$ A_k = \{ S^*_{k-1}< a, S_k \ge a\} \quad \text{for} \quad k \le n $$
such that
$$ \{ S_n^* \ge a\} = \sum_{k\le n}A_k $$
also following this method I had to introduce the events $B_k$ (I don't know exactly how they look) such that
$$ \sum_{k\le n}A_kB_k \subset \{S_n > a - b\},\quad P(B_k) \ge 1/2. $$
But I got nothing. May be I need to use this strategy:
$$ \mathbf{P}(\max_\limits{1\le k \le n} S_k - \mathbf{E}|S_n| \ge a - \mathbf{E}|S_n|) \le \mathbf{P}(\max_\limits{1\le k \le n} S_k - \mathbf{E}S_n \ge c) $$
and show that right part of this equation is less than $ 2\mathbf{P}(S_n \ge c), $ where $c = a - \mathbf{E}|S_n|$.

I'm stuck. I will be very grateful for any help.